# Any simple function which behaves like this?

Tags: functions, simulation

[image: http://imgur.com/itkKA]

I'm looking for this behavior to simulate the movement of the recoil of a gun.

I'm not sure the recoil exactly has this shape, that's a wild guess.

I'm looking for a function that does this approximately, or simulate the movement caused by recoil...

Something like f(t)=...

Any idea ?

Somebody told me about some probabilistic function of Maxwell something, but I can't use it without a time dependent formula.

Comment: Which kind of simulation? Different applications require different degrees of accuracy -- "I'm designing a gun stand" is not the same as "I'm animating a ship firing a broadside and want it to look somewhat realistic".

Comment: making a game, using 32 bit precision, which is not much but quite enough. Has to be fast.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks somewhat like a rescaled version of $y = x e^{-x}$.  Try $y=cx e^{1-cx}$ with various choices of $c>1$.  For example, try entering `(5x)e^(1-5x) from 0 to 1` into [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com).